# Regular expression blacklist

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone explain to me the meaning of the following query:

```
SELECT message.message
FROM message CROSS JOIN
     Blacklist
 WHERE(message.message LIKE {fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT('%', Blacklist.Words)}, '%')});
```

I know what cross join means, but I want to know what exactly **"{fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT('%', Blacklist.Words)}, '%')})"** function does in this query.

Comment: Looks like template code used to generate the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Transact SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation:

> CONCAT functions returns a string resulting from the concatenation,
>   or joining, of two or more string values.

Your code uses the [ODBC compatible CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function that gets only 2 parameters. That's the reason for fn prefix.

So this line:

```
{fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT('%', Blacklist.Words)}, '%')})
```

is equivalent to:

```
CONCAT('%', Blacklist.Words, '%')
```

Sample output:

If your `Words` field  is `apple`, the output for LIKE statement would be:

```
SELECT message.message
FROM message CROSS JOIN
     Blacklist
 WHERE(message.message LIKE '%apple%');
```

Comment: Never knew about these ODBC compatible functions... +1 from me.